# Is there any solution to solve the deadlock created here?

Tags: java

Below is the code.

[Gregorian variable definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5KdB.png)

[The circled content in the attached screenshots indicate the error highlighted in yellow on the logs shown below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJVJp.png)

I used a Gregorian calendar Class in java to initialize a calendar variable and manipulate date values using cal.add() method etc.

This is the error received in logs:

```
"http-100.20.2.40-8080-6" - Thread t@247
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
    at java.util.SimpleTimeZone.getOffsets(SimpleTimeZone.java:533)
    - waiting to lock <6ed79c47> (a java.util.SimpleTimeZone) owned by "http-100.20.2.40-8080-1" t@223
    at java.util.SimpleTimeZone.getOffset(SimpleTimeZone.java:522)
    at java.util.SimpleTimeZone.inDaylightTime(SimpleTimeZone.java:834)
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getOffsets(ZoneInfo.java:282)
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getOffsets(ZoneInfo.java:225)
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(GregorianCalendar.java:2024)
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(GregorianCalendar.java:1996)
    at java.util.Calendar.setTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1110)
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.add(GregorianCalendar.java:999)
    at
```

> com.thrasys.xnet.erp.ordering.manager.OrderTimingManager.CalculateIntraDayTimes(OrderTimingManager.java:640)

```
    at com.thrasys.xnet.erp.ordering.manager.OrderTimingManager.GetRepeatTimesArray(OrderTimingManager.java:489)
    at com.thrasys.xnet.erp.ordering.manager.OrderTimingManager.HandleOrderOccurrences(OrderTimingManager.java:58)
```

Even though a singleton class is used , I got a thread dump.
Code has been running properly till yesterday. Suddenly , there is a deadlock.

Is it because of difference in JVM Timezone and DB timezone ?

JDK version : 1.6.45.

Comment: Please provide the complete stacktrace

Comment: I would suggest using JSR 310 for date times, and Java 8 if not Java 11 if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## java.time

> any solution to solve the deadlock created here?

Yes.

- Use modern *java.time* classes.  [Thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) by design.
- Never use `Calendar` again. Replaced by [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago, with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;

System.out.println( zdt ) ;  // Generate text representing this value in standard ISO 8601 format.

Locale locale = new Locale( "ar" , "TN" ) ; // Arabic language, Tunisia cultural norms.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;  // Generate text describing this moment in a localized format.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).